# error while running pod defination file in kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

error when creating "pod-defination.yml":

> pods "myapp" is forbidden: pod does not have
>   "kubernetes.io/config.mirror" annotation, node
>   "ip-172-31-38-73.us-east-2.compute.internal" can only create mirror
>   pods

```
apiVersion: v1  

kind: Pod 

metadata:
   labels:
     app: myapp
spec:
   containers:
      - name: nginx-container
      - image: nginx
```

Answer (score 4):

So, you have 3 problems in one here. This is partial answer unfortunately.

1)  @Dinesh is absolutely right with an image.

```
   containers:
      - name: nginx-container
      - image: nginx
```

With your config it tries to use 2 images - `nginx-container` and `nginx`. Instead of this you want only `nginx` with name: nginx-container

correct is

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
```

2) You should always set `name:` in metadata - this is required field. Without specifying .metadata.name you will get `resource name may not be empty`

```
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "kind":"Pod" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "labels":map["app":"myapp"] "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["containers":[map["image":"nginx" "name":"nginx-container"]]]]}
from server for: "pod-defination.yml": resource name may not be empty
```

As per [Understanding Kubernetes Objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#required-fields)

> In the .yaml file for the Kubernetes object you want to create, you’ll
>   need to set values for the following fields:
>
> - apiVersion - Which version of the Kubernetes API you’re using to    create this object
> - kind - What kind of object you want to create
> - metadata - Data that helps uniquely identify the object, including a    name string, UID, and optional namespace
> - spec - What state you desire    for the object

Also as per [metadata API Conventions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata)

> Every object kind MUST have the following metadata in a nested object
>   field called "metadata":
>
> - namespace: a namespace is a DNS compatible label that objects are subdivided into. The default namespace is 'default'. See the namespace
>     docs for more.
> - name: a string that uniquely identifies this object within the current namespace (see the identifiers docs). This value is used in
>     the path when retrieving an individual object.
> - uid: a unique in time and space value (typically an RFC 4122 generated identifier, see the identifiers docs) used to distinguish
>     between objects with the same name that have been deleted and
>     recreated

3)pod does not have "kubernetes.io/config.mirror" annotation

> pods "blabla" is forbidden: pod does not have
>   "kubernetes.io/config.mirror" annotation, node "blablabla" can only
>   create mirror pods

Above error is typical for situations when you have an issue with [NodeRestriction admission plugin]{https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#noderestriction}

> An admission controller is a piece of code that intercepts requests to
>   the Kubernetes API server prior to persistence of the object, but
>   after the request is authenticated and authorized. […] Admission
>   controllers may be “validating”, “mutating”, or both. Mutating
>   controllers may modify the objects they admit; validating controllers
>   may not. […] If any of the controllers in either phase reject the
>   request, the entire request is rejected immediately and an error is
>   returned to the end-user.

NodeRestriction admission controller:

> This admission controller limits the Node and Pod objects a kubelet
>   can modify. In order to be limited by this admission controller,
>   kubelets must use credentials in the system:nodes group, with a
>   username in the form system:node:. Such kubelets will only
>   be allowed to modify their own Node API object, and only modify Pod
>   API objects that are bound to their node. In Kubernetes 1.11+,
>   kubelets are not allowed to update or remove taints from their Node
>   API object.

As per [EKS kubernetes platform versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/platform-versions.html) we can see that `NodeRestriction` is part of Enabled Admission Controllers.

> ​NamespaceLifecycle, LimitRanger, ServiceAccount, DefaultStorageClass,
>   ResourceQuota, DefaultTolerationSeconds, NodeRestriction,
>   MutatingAdmissionWebhook, ValidatingAdmissionWebhook, PodSecurityPolicy

3 month ago there was already [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439973/is-it-possible-adviseable-to-turn-off-the-noderestriction-plugin-on-eks) but it left without any replies.

As EKS in managed by AWS control plane - seems it is not possible modify built-in admission controllers, but you can look into the Dynamic Admission Controllers and Admission Webhooks.   More info can be found in [Dynamic Admission Control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/).

As per [Amazon EKS Enables Support for Kubernetes Dynamic Admission Controllers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-eks-enables-support-for-kubernetes-dynamic-admission-cont/) - EKS supports dynamic admission controllers, allowing customers to deploy custom webhooks that enable additional open source tools for controlling network traffic and monitoring Kubernetes clusters on AWS.

I would recommend you use [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) to manually create cluster with all the option you need.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Please try below as image element is not an array

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
```